# How to set-up a nice splash-screen when logging in on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, login, splash

I would like to set-up a splash-screen that says "ACCESS GRANTED" shown when I'm logging in into my account on Ubuntu (after GDM).

What possibilities do I have?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try gnome-splashscreen-manager or startupmanager. I have not tested them; make sure they add something to your gnome-session-properties.